# gradle 5: project.distsDir deprecated, replacement?

Tags: gradle

gradle 5: project.distsDir deprecated. What is the replacement?

```
new File(project.buildDir, project.distsDirName)
```

Why is it deprecated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a consequence of Gradle adopting the [`Provider` API](https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/lazy_configuration.html) to enable lazy evaluation of properties.